# Time-fixed effects in a randomized controlled trial?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, clinical-trials, randomized-tests

When analyzing the results of an RCT, it is not uncommon to see a unit (e.g. cluster) fixed effects in the linear regression model but I have never seen time fixed effects while time FEs are pretty much mandatory in quasi-experimental settings. Is there a reason? I am thinking maybe it is related to statistical power as in the inclusion of time FE would reduce the power too much, but I cannot find any references.

On a side note, if there is a fixed effects in a model for an RCT it must have more than one  time period right?

Thank you!